Programmer is not responding error
I currently am running into problems with my new Arduino board. The complete details are here with log info and other troubleshooting steps https://forum.arduino.cc/t/programmer-is-not-responding-error/1243022. I just bought a new Arduino Uno with WIFI and I cant download the code to the device. Any new suggestions on how to fix this?
EDIT
After the comment I updated the question to include everything from the other forum. Below is the original question
I'm new to Arduino, I just received my first board the other day, Arduino Uno with WIFI. I even bought a USB cable in the same order. I started playing around with it today and every time I try to upload the code I get this error. I turned to Google and found this avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding | SOLVED which has a number of different things to try. I tried all but using a new board or USB cable as they are both brand new, PC or manually installing the drivers because I cant find it in the device manager on Windows. I'm using Windows 11.
Logs
FQBN: arduino:avr:unowifi
Using board 'unowifi' from platform in folder: C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6
Detecting libraries used...
C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_DEV_ED -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DESP_CH_UART -DESP_CH_UART_BR=19200 -IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino -IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\variants\standard C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6\sketch\Play.ino.cpp -o nul
Generating function prototypes...
C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_DEV_ED -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DESP_CH_UART -DESP_CH_UART_BR=19200 -IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino -IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\variants\standard C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6\sketch\Play.ino.cpp -o C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\3413583233\sketch_merged.cpp
C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\builtin\tools\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\3413583233\sketch_merged.cpp
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_DEV_ED -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DESP_CH_UART -DESP_CH_UART_BR=19200 "-IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\variants\standard" "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6\sketch\Play.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6\sketch\Play.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\cores\arduino_avr_unowifi_e2a5c97a567227dd7f86c91bbbe2dd32\core.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.elf" "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6\sketch\Play.ino.cpp.o" "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/..\..\cores\arduino_avr_unowifi_e2a5c97a567227dd7f86c91bbbe2dd32\core.a" "-LC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6" -lm
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.elf" "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.eep"
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.elf" "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.hex"
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.elf"
Sketch uses 924 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
"C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega328p -carduino "-PCOM3" -b115200 -D "-Uflash:w:C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\4BACC01029730E9B8607320D444555A6/Play.ino.hex:i"
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM3
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM3": The system cannot find the file specified.
avrdude done.  Thank you.
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
Also trying to check for a firmware update results in and I cant change it to check.


Please add the relevant information from your link to your question here (edit).  Do not expect users here to go to an external forum to read about your problem.

Assuming it isn't the com port selection... I support a couple AtMega based products and we use avrdude on windows (many versions over the years). I found that there are different builds out there (ie presumably using different unix-emulation setups to port to win32/64), of which some work just fine across all versions, and others do not ... I'll try to dig up the one we settled on, don't recall atm

"I cant find it in the device manager on Windows". Have you tried expanding the Ports (COM & LPT) section in Device Manager; that is where such devices usually hide. The forum post also say that you have bought the Arduino UNO R4 WiFi, but you have selected a different board (see also https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-r4-wifi/r4-wifi-getting-started/).

@PeteW I'm using whichever version of avrdude is used in the Arduino IDE 2.3.2.

I've never used that one :-/

Yes all I see under Ports (COM & LPT) in device manager is USB Serial Device (COM3)

The Arduino UNO R4 WiFi is not an AVR board, but it looks like you are trying to use an AVR board profile. I suspect you have the wrong board selected.

I purchased the Arduino Uno with WIFI capabilities so in the IDE I chose Arduino Uno WIFI for the board.

The document I linked to (which is on the Arduino website), says to use the 'Arduino UNO R4 WiFi' board profile. You may also need to install the board profile from the Board Manager.

the error suggests that avrdude is bombing out just opening the port

anyway we had good results with avrdude 7.1 , binary build by this guy - https://github.com/mariusgreuel/avrdude/releases -- but ofc you'd think the Arduino IDE would be well tested

Also, this is probably a much better fit for Arduino StackExchange https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

@user85471 That worked, I installed the correct board package, which gave me more board options with Arduino Uno R4 WIFI as one of them. That board worked. If you want to make an answer out of your comment I will accept it as the answer.

I didnt know there was an Arduino Stack Exchange I'll check it out.

According to the linked forum thread, the board in question is actually an Arduino UNO R4 WiFi, which is not an AVR board, so the wrong board is selected.
According to the guide at https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-r4-wifi/r4-wifi-getting-started/, the Arduino UNO R4 WiFi needs to be added through the Board Manager. That will allow the Arduino UNO R4 WiFi board to be selected.

Thank you much I normally try to read the docs and tutorials before I start playing with new toys somehow I missed or forgot this part.
